# Seems you're trying to access 'ReactNative.createClass'

Tags: javascript, babeljs, react-native

I run the following codes to create a component that renders a view but it generated some error. The codes are as follows:

```js
var React = require('react-native');

var Dictionary = React.createClass({
 
 render: function() {
  var layout = 
   <React.View style = { styles.parent } >
    
    <React.Text>
     Type something in English:
    </React.Text>
    
    <React.TextInput />
    
    <React.Text style = { styles.germanLabel } >
     It's German equivalent is:
    </React.Text>
    
    <React.Text style = { styles.germanWord } >
    </React.Text>
    
   </React.View>
  ;
  return layout;
 },
});

var styles = React.StyleSheet.create({
 
 // For the container View
 parent: {
  padding: 16
 },
 
 // For the Text Label
 germanLabel: {
  marginTop: 20,
  fontWeight: 'bold'
 },
 
 // For the Text meaning
 germanWord: {
  marginTop: 15,
  fontSize: 30,
  fontStyle: 'italic'
 }
});

React.AppRegistry.registerComponent('Dictionary', () => Dictionary);
```

and got the following error:

[image]

I even tried including `import React, { Component } from 'react';` but it doesn't work. Could it be because of outdated version or something? I am not very good in react-native.

Comment: Is that the full code from that file? You said you also included `import React from 'react'` but that would be declaring the variable `React` twice, which isn't allowed. There can only be one `React` declared per file.

Comment: @dogui Yes that is the full code from that file. I was following a tutorial on [link](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-dictionary-app-using-react-native-for-android--cms-24969). I do not understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: You should `import React from 'react'` and import your components from `react-native`. i.e. `import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'`. Then remove the `React.` from your components. (`React.Text` should be `Text`)

Comment: @Dan Thanks for your help. It seems that I've failed to write javascript import statement correctly.